# How can I pass an event accross Threads in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, events

In Java, how can I pass an event from a child Thread to the main thread, **without freezing the main thread in a loop** ?

Online I could only find solutions that involve the main thread stuck in an infinite while loop checking for events in a `shared thread-safe event FIFO queue` (where the child puts the events).
Then sleeping for `x` sec and starting again.

I need the main Thread active and doing other things, such as being able to process events form the gui. And when something happens in the child thread, the main thread has to, say, invoke `.eventHappened()`.

Comment: what you need is a **listener**  thread that passes the event data to main **OBJECT** when there is something to do. This event data will be processed in  the listener thread. Otherwise you need the main thread do the checking. How many user names are you using?

Comment: Details about your threading model, please. Raw threads? Executors? AWT? Swing? SWT?

Comment: Main thread is where I create all the gui (Swing). The other is a raw worker thread, downloading stuff and parsing it.
Efektive, thanks for your answers, but on the listener thread I'm then stuck with the same issue, how do I give the processed events to the main Thread?

Comment: *I'd like to know regardless for future use and personal understanding*, but in this specific case, I need the events on the main thread so that I can update the Swing gui accordingly. I have read in several posts that bad things happen if you pass swing components to several threads and/or try to update them from separate threads.

Comment: Then have a queue where the gui posts work and a second queue where work results are posted. To present the results in the UI you would need another thread and some async invocations of the ui

Comment: If the main thread is stuck listening for "done work" on the queue, it will not process gui events.

Comment: Read the comments

Comment: What you suggest would require me to update the gui from the listener thread, upon an event being completely processed. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, To avoid exceptions async invocations will do the trick. All the ui frameworks have them. A worker thread and a listener thread. The worker thread could be a pool. Queues need to be concurrent. If this helps you I will post it as an naswer

Comment: So .InvokeLater in the listener thread? May I ask why exactly this needs to be async?

Comment: Read comments. The gui thread needs to have total control of the state of the UI

Comment: Ok post an answer, I'll select it I think I'm understanding now. I just want to understand why on  a second thread we need InvokeLater (to run code on AWT dispatch thread) whereas from the main thread, where we create the gui, we can call gui stuff directly.

Comment: done. Logging off. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid freezing the UI this should do the trick:

1) Incoming work concurrent queue where a worker thread or pool of worker threads are checking in their run methods.

2) Work done concurrent queue where a listener thread, different from the UI thread, checks in a loop. The listener thread invokes updates to the UI using asynchronous facilities/methods to avoid UI exceptions.

So the UI thread feeds the incoming work queue with events or data. The worker threads pick it up, do the work and post results to work done queue.

Listener thread checks for new items in the work done queue and post results asynchronously to the UI.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this:  In this method, we need async access to AWT dispatch thread, because the specs say that all gui code needs to be run from that thread. So to go there, we use SwintUtils.InvokeLater. But then, why can we just call methods directly from the main thread? It is afterall the main program's thread, not the AWT event dispatch thread. Am I wrong?

Comment: AsyncInvoke later is another "do work" queue but for the UI main thread. The internals  of this are transparent for us.

Comment: The UI main thread being the thread where I first create the gui elements?

Comment: Yes. If you look at the threads created by the jvm you will notice this thread, among others, like the GC, etc

Comment: I see. So from the moment I create the first gui element, it stops being the main thread and I am in the UI dispatch thread basically

Comment: The ui elements live inside the ui thread. They respond to events sent by the dispatch thread

Comment: I understand that, but from the thread where you create them (which is not the UI thread, that's where they live, we are in the main thread form the initial main method) you don't need to pass the updates to the dispatch thread manually. You can just call them directly. From other threads, you do need to use the dispatch thread. I can't understand this difference.

Comment: Ui thread creates ui elements not main thread to have control over them. This is beyond the scope of the question

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use a child thread that way, you would probably need to use a concurrent queue.

If you are using swing you can use SwingUtilities.invokeLater() to execute code. It would then run it in a backgroundt thread instead of using a child thread manually.